# Is the MAC address encapsulated in the Internet packets?

Tags: privacy, mac-address

This might be a stupid question, but what is the range of the MAC addresses? Are these somehow leaking to the Internet with packets that a user sends (so they know where to return)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is awesome: it contains a lot of useful information. In this case, the following schema:

[image: MAC address schema (from Wikipedia)]

So there are basically 46 bits for global unicast MAC addresses, for 2<sup>46</sup> possible addresses.

MAC addresses do *not* leak beyond your local link (machines on the same LAN as you see your MAC address, other people do not). IP addresses are used for global addressing, not MAC addresses. **Exception:** if you use IPv6, your machine may obtain an automatically allocated IPv6 address, and the scheme for creating such addresses uses MAC addresses, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64). In that case, your MAC address can be inferred from the source address in the IP packets your machine emits.